# How to customize Angular based Bootstrap Event Calender?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, calendar

I am using this [tool](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar) in one of my application for Event management. This tool however itself is an angular version of [this](https://github.com/Serhioromano/bootstrap-calendar) tool. The original tools uses various templates and underscore templating engine for rendering calendar and its various views.

I do not have much knowledge of underscore, but I was able to tweak the original code's template to make few changes and customize the view.

However, since mine is an Angular app, I migrated to the Angular version now. Now, I am having a hard time, understanding how the templates have been converted in Angular. Where are they placed? How could I identify one and above all how do I change a template.

For example: I would like to change `the way an event is shown in the month view (circle)` to `the way it is shown in week view (strips)`. There are few other customization that I require.

There seems to be almost NO questions on this tool on SO. Few links that I found across internet were not relevant. While tweaking around I found :

```
var map = {
        "./calendar.html": 14,
        "./calendarDayView.html": 15,
        "./calendarHourList.html": 16,
        "./calendarMonthCell.html": 17,
        "./calendarMonthCellEvents.html": 18,
        "./calendarMonthView.html": 19,
        "./calendarSlideBox.html": 20,
        "./calendarWeekView.html": 21,
        "./calendarYearView.html": 22
    };
```

Few models are being exported, but I am unable to completely grasp it.

Can someone have a look and direct me to a better direction.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out you can completely replace various views of this calendar, which is just pretty awesome. Perhaps the biggest advantage over all other available versions.

You can keep your templates within `<script>` tags in your html (`index.html` may be). and you can pass on these templates to replace the original ones. You can find all original ones [here](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar/tree/master/src/templates)

Passing these templates to directive is easy and can be done as:

`custom-template-urls="{calendarYearView: 'customYearCell.html', calendarMonthCell: 'customMonthCell.html', calendarSlideBox:'customSlideBox.html'}"`

This shall replace your entire template. Hope it helps someone.